# Save for later use functionality in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database

I want to know the best way to make a **Save for Later, Add to Workplace** functionality to my website. The only way I can think of(I know) is storing the IDs of the projects, medias and actors in my database. Each time a user presses Save for later store the id of the project in a new table in my database.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, just put it into your database.  You can even create a "draft" system where you put a status on a particular record that identifies it as a draft and when it is approved change the status to "approved" or something.  There are many ways to do it.

Comment: Well, I was just trying to explain how you could extend it further.  If it isn't applicable or something you're interested in, don't bother.

Comment: You are talking about  the projects? To add an extra functionality, if they are approved.

Comment: I'm saying to your records you could add an auto-save or draft feature whereby you could create a record with a certain indicated status; whether it be "saved for later" or "draft" and present it in a manner accordingly.

Comment: Do not introduce unnecessary additional tables, you can easily complete this by introducing filters.

Comment: I deleted my answer because you downvoted and gave no reason.